# Jquery Parsing json and get specific value

Tags: jquery, json

This is my response

```
["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"JOHN\"}","{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"MICHEAL\"}"]
var json = JSON.parse(demp);
console.log(json[0].id); says undefined.
```

How to get id and name ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a loop to iterate in array as you have suggested in the question.

To me your response is an array so you should `JSON.parse()` the array instead just `var demp`:

```
var DEMP = ["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"JOHN\"}", "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"MICHEAL\"}"];
for (var i = 0, syze = DEMP.length; i < syze; i++) {
   var json = JSON.parse(DEMP[i]);
   console.log('Response ID is --> '+json.id + 
               ' Response name is --> ' + json.name);
}
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUKjf/)

Answer (score 2):

There should be no quote arround the `{}`, otherwise it's not a list of parseable objects, but just a list of strings. This is what your json should look like:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"JOHN"}, {"id":2,"name":"MICHEAL"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res                  =   [{"id":1,"name":"JOHN"}, {"id":2,"name":"MICHEAL"}];
var response             =   JSON.stringify(res);
response                 =   JSON.parse(response);
console.log(response[0].id);
console.log(response[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array and then convert the array values to JSON.

```
var obj = ["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"JOHN\"}","{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"MICHEAL\"}"];

for(var i = 0, len = obj.length; i<len;i++) {
   var json = JSON.parse(obj[i]);
   console.log(json.id);
}
```